# How to align three images specifically?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm having trouble aligning three images in the middle of the page.

Let's say image #1 is around 500px high by 500px wide. Image #2 and #3 are 250px high and 500x wide.
I want image #1 to be on the left and image #2 and #3 next to image #1.
There would be some margin between them so that they wouldn't be RIGHT next to each other, but for now, I need to figure out a way to align them.

```
------------------    -------------------
|                 |   |                 |
|                 |   |                 |
|                 |   |                 |
|                 |   |_________________|
|                 |   
|                 |   |-----------------|
|                 |   |                 |
|                 |   |                 |
-------------------   -------------------
```

Does that make sense...?

Also, they're not buttons or anything. Just plan images.

Comment: A graphical illustration would be helpful.

Comment: forget an illustration. How about "what have you tried?"  - we who volunteer our lives on this site like to know we're not just doing your work for you. We're here to "help" not just work.

Comment: Define _"align them"_... vertically, horizontally, along their top/bottom edges, equal spacing, centered, what?

Comment: I shamelessly hijacked the question to illustrate the request. This is what I believe the OP wanted. If I'm wrong... shame on me for putting an ounce of interest in it

Comment: @KaiQing, if that's what he was asking for, then this question was even more poorly written than I first thought.

Comment: @sparky - true but I deduce this entirely based on the dimensions he listed. Because 2 and 3 are half the HEIGHT of 1 it makes some sense to believe this is his intention.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/chmHH/

Works in Chrome, haven't checked other browsers.

HTML (I recommend using class names)

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/200"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/200"/>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
img{
    display:inline;
}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/chmHH/1/

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/98" class="top"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/98" class="bottom"/>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
img{
    display:inline;
}
img.top{
    vertical-align:top;
}
img.bottom{
    vertical-align:baseline;
    margin-left:-204px;
}
​
​
```

Comment: zzz http://jsfiddle.net/chmHH/3/

Answer (score 1):

**First approach.**

If you can change a little bit the markup, the easiest approach consists into adding an extra box for the images, which should be rendered in column. Then you would change the box `display` property so that it does not start on a new line.

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/"/>
<div class="inline-block">
  <img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/100/50/"/>
  <img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/100/50/"/>  
</div>
```

**Second approach.**

Use CSS `float` property. [All you may ever want to know about float is in this css-tricks' post](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

And that's the final result.

```css
#big {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}
.small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img id="big" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/"/>
<img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/100/50/"/>
<img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/100/50/"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

if only 3 images, and using html, then try aligning left, middle, and right, like this:

```
<img src="whatever you want" align=left height="whatever" width="whatever">
<img src="whatever you want" align=right height="whatever" width="whatever">
<img src="whatever you want" position:absolute; left:"whatever%"; top:"whatever%; height:"whatever px"; width:"whatever px";>
```

you must also set the width and height to a small enough size so all will fit with a space, depending on your screen resolution.  Just try to shrink image size to a small size and will probably work.

Comment: -1 for using `align` attribute.

Comment: pretty sure align is not valid in html5.

Comment: I don't think it's valid in HTML4.01 either.  Correction:  **deprecated** in HTML4.01.

Comment: Probably true. This is the first google result I found on it: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/blatalignmultim.htm

Comment: Wow, this answer just keeps getting worse.  What a mess inside that third `img` tag.  **Proof-read what you post, man!**

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thanks so much, everyone! 
I had an image sample but for some reason, my file isn't opening and I couldn't upload it. But that sample up there that someone so nicely put up for me was exactly what I was looking for (I didn't think about using characters to illustrate the image).
Thanks,s guys! You guys are the best!

Comment: You realize that there is no such `img` `attribute`'s called `position`, `left`, or `top`.

Comment: @user1772537, pay attention to the comments and edit history on your OP...  KaiQing is who fixed your question.  And this answer by user1851853 can't possibly work... it's full of syntax errors and deprecated HTML.

Comment: I fear for the future of the internet if this answer has somehow been accepted by any living soul! - and sorry user185. it takes a lot to get me to downvote but you just kept soaring this into the abyss

Comment: @KaiQing, me too... what a disaster... ten edits and he still couldn't find the syntax errors, even after I pointed to them.

Comment: @KaiQing, this code demonstrates how forgiving browsers can be.  It would be a better Internet if the browser rendered a blank page on syntax errors instead of a "best guess".  And this question/answer demonstrates that people don't read comments.